# Dijkstra's Algorithm team project not running because I named it Dijkstra(Project name)?

Tags: c#

Was working on a team project in C#, I called it Dijkstra's Algorithm,  and when I was done writing my code down I went to debug using Visual Studio 2010 and I would keep getting an error like this:

!https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-M8DCWHZMhig/UXYtd_9z3OI/AAAAAAAAAJQ/njtUVLTHxq4/w497-h373/Error.png

This kept happening more and more when I re-did the project under a similar name. Only when I took out the name Dijkstra would it properly run and debug.

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of the apostrophe, not Dijsktra. Name it DijkstrasAlgorithm or somesuch and you should be fine

Comment: You're welcome. Mark as answer if it works, so that other people can use it too.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you use symbol: '

I suggest using only [A-Z][a-z][0-9] characters while naming project (especially without whitespace), it will save you a lot of time.